# Java Calendar object retrieving wrong date?

Tags: java, calendar

```
/**
 * Gets an instance of GMT Calendar.
 *
 * @return a new <code>Calendar</code> object
 */
public static Calendar getGMTCalendar()
{
    return Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.US);
}

/**
 * @return The month (eg. Calenday.MAY) value for the date.
 */
public static int getMonth(Date date)
{
    Calendar c = getGMTCalendar();
    System.out.println("date ::"+date.toString());
    c.setTime(date);
    int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    System.out.println("date after calendar is set ::"+c.getTime()+",Month="+month);
    return c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
}
```

Above is the code snipped I am using.When I try retrieving the month of the date I am passing to getMonth() like

int month=DateUtil.getMonth(date);         (date is 10-01-2010)

The month I am expecting is 8(0-Jan,1-Feb...8-Sept,9-oct) but what I get here is
month=8.
I tried debugging and found that in the function getMonth() when i set the time using
c.setTime(date) the date is set to 09-31-2010 i.e a day before the date passed.
I am using INtellij Idea as the Ide 
 Can anyone help??

Comment: What is the *exact* value of `date`, in terms of what gets retuned from `date.getTime()`? I suspect that will answer everything...

Comment: @Jon Skeet  :I modified the code to print the date and month and this is what I got.  date ::Fri Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2010
date after calendar is set ::Fri Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2010,Month=8     .Month should be equal to 9 this time.Just cant figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I asked for the result of calling `date.getTime()`, because that gives the *underlying data*. You've also changed your mind about whether you're wanting it to be September or October...

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Sir,here is the result of date.getTime()  ,date ::1285871400000   for Oct 01 2010. Many thanks.

Comment: That's not October 1st 2010. It's September 30th. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now we've got the *real* data out, the problem is with your initial date.

Personally I find it easiest to diagnose this sort of thing using Joda Time:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1285871400000L,
                                   DateTimeZone.UTC);
        System.out.println(dt);
    }
}
```

That will definitely show everything in UTC... and it prints 2010-09-30T18:30:00.000Z. So the instant you're passing into the calendar is in September, not October. It's giving you the right result for the data you're giving it, as you've specified a GMT time zone - you're just not giving it the data you thought you were.

You need to understand that `Date` just represents an *instant* in time, with no reference to calendar system or time zone. So while that date value printed out October 1st *for you* because of your default time zone, it really is still the instant which is in the evening of September 30th in UTC in the ISO calendar.

To be honest, if you can possibly use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in calendar types, you should... but you still need to be careful of the system default time zone being applied when you don't want it to be.

Comment: @Jon Thanks a lot. So is it the system default time zone that's creating a problem here?The same program runs well on other machines.What could be the probable solution?? Many thanks

Comment: @mglauche Well,as of now,in this case, I wont be able to use Joda time.The code runs well on other machines and has been deployed.Many thanks-

Comment: @wantobegeek: What's been deployed - the code which comes up with the wrong `Date` value? Ick...

Comment: @Jon well Sir,if there is something wrong with the code,why does it not cause any problem on other machines?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a timezone with a negative offset (i.e. the US, for example) and set the GMT date to the first day of a month with time 00:00:00, the local time will be in the previous day (and previous month).  Check to make sure you aren't retrieving the local time from the Calendar object.